# Shuffle elements in AVX register

Tags: c, x86, simd, avx

I have a vector with doubles stored in an AVX register with elements `{a0,a1,a2,a3}`. Now, I want to make three new vectors (which also should be stored as `__m256d` variables), lets say b, c and d, containing the following elements:

```
b = {a0,a1,a0,a0}
c = {a1,a2,a2,a1}
d = {a2,a3,a3,a2}
```

How can I do this using AVX?

Comment: You mean with AVX1 only?  If you can use AVX2, it's more efficient: `b = _mm256_permute4x64_pd(a, _MM_SHUFFLE(0,1,0,0));`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See how a compiler does it, using `gcc` vector extensions for `-march=core-avx2`

```
#include <stdint.h>

typedef double v4df __attribute__((vector_size(32)));
typedef uint64_t v4u64 __attribute__((vector_size(32)));

void foo(v4df a, v4df *b, v4df *c, v4df *d)
{
  *b = __builtin_shuffle(a, (v4u64){0, 1, 0, 0});
  *c = __builtin_shuffle(a, (v4u64){1, 2, 2, 1});
  *d = __builtin_shuffle(a, (v4u64){2, 3, 3, 2});
}
```

gcc-4.8.4 -march=core-avx2 -O3 produces:

```
vpermpd $4, %ymm0, %ymm1
vmovapd %ymm1, (%rdi)
vpermpd $105, %ymm0, %ymm1
vpermpd $190, %ymm0, %ymm0
vmovapd %ymm1, (%rsi)
vmovapd %ymm0, (%rdx)
vzeroupper
ret
```

gcc-4.8.4 -march=corei7-avx -O3 produces:

```
vinsertf128 $1, %xmm0, %ymm0, %ymm1
vpermilpd   $2, %ymm1, %ymm1
vmovapd %ymm1, (%rdi)
vperm2f128  $33, %ymm0, %ymm0, %ymm1
vshufpd $9, %ymm1, %ymm0, %ymm1
vmovapd %ymm1, (%rsi)
vperm2f128  $49, %ymm0, %ymm0, %ymm0
vpermilpd   $6, %ymm0, %ymm0
vmovapd %ymm0, (%rdx)
vzeroupper
ret
```